# Accessing state after updating it retrieves outdated version of it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state

React newbie here. I know this may be related to React not updating state right away but I have read other post and haven't found a solution/explanation that fits my case.

`handleCreateTimeEntry` is calling `setDefaultTag` which updates the `Settings` state.

When the `Settings` state is accessed next to instantiate the `eventToLoad` constant, the retrieved hash is outdated and `eventToLoad.tagIds` is still an empty array despite that `setDefaultTag` is adding a value to it.

Am I right to guess that the `Settings` state is not yet updated at this point? Or am I missing something else? What could be a workaround to this?

```
  const handleCreateTimeEntry = async (eventId: string) => {
    setDefaultTag(eventId);
    const eventToLoad = Settings[eventId];
    await createTimeEntry(
      eventToLoad.tagIds
    );
  };

  const setDefaultTag = (eventId: string) => {
    const defaultTag: string = "default_tag"

    const updatedSettings: ISettings = { ...Settings };
    let currentTagIds = [...updatedSettings[eventId].tagIds];
    currentTagIds.push(defaultTag);

    updatedSettings[eventId] = {
      ...updatedSettings[eventId],
      tagIds: currentTagIds,
    };
    setSettings(updatedSettings)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because setState is asynchronous (it will dispatch the updated Settings value when it has time). I have provided several possible solutions, dependent on need-case.

## 1. Return `updatedSettings`

This one is pretty self-explanatory, just return the updated value to ensure you are using the same value which is dispatched to `Settings`. However if `createTimeEntry` is also dependent on `Settings` this may be problematic (possible solution: accept another parameter on createTimeEntry to accept updatedSettings?).

```js
  const handleCreateTimeEntry = async (eventId: string) => {
    const updatedSettings = setDefaultTag(eventId);
    const eventToLoad = updatedSettings[eventId];
    await createTimeEntry(
      eventToLoad.tagIds
    );
  };

  const setDefaultTag = (eventId: string) => {
    const defaultTag: string = "default_tag"

    const updatedSettings: ISettings = { ...Settings };
    let currentTagIds = [...updatedSettings[eventId].tagIds];
    currentTagIds.push(defaultTag);

    updatedSettings[eventId] = {
      ...updatedSettings[eventId],
      tagIds: currentTagIds,
    };
    setSettings(updatedSettings)
    return updatedSettings
  }
```

## 2. Use dispatch callback on setState functions

If you need you can use the dispatch function available on [`useState` hooks](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState). The pattern is as follows:

```js
// This pattern is super useful for ensuring all previous events are dispatched first, 
// then calculating a new value after they are all completed
setSettings((prevSettingsValue) => {return newSettingsValue})
```

This could be helpful for refactoring your `setDefaultTag` function.

```js
  const handleCreateTimeEntry = async (eventId: string) => {
    // pass a callback to createTimeEntry into setDefaultTag
    setDefaultTag(eventId, async (newSettings) => {
      const eventToLoad = newSettings[eventId];
      await createTimeEntry(eventToLoad.tagIds)
    });
  };

  const setDefaultTag = (eventId: string, callback: (newSettings: ISettings) => Promise<void> | void) => {
    const defaultTag: string = "default_tag"

    // prevSettings is always up-to-date
    setSettings((prevSettings) => {
      const updatedSettings: ISettings = { ...prevSettings };
      let currentTagIds = [...updatedSettings[eventId].tagIds];
      currentTagIds.push(defaultTag);

      updatedSettings[eventId] = {
        ...updatedSettings[eventId],
        tagIds: currentTagIds,
      };
      // use the callback with the updatedSettings
      callback(updatedSettings)
      // return a value to set Settings to updatedSettings
      return updatedSettings
    })
  }
```

However, this could cause problems as well since the `setState` callback is not awaitable, but `createTimeEntry` is async. This can be resolved by wrapping `setSettings` in a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). This has the expected side-effect of making everything wrapping `createTimeEntry` async as well

```js
  const handleCreateTimeEntry = async (eventId: string) => {
    await setDefaultTag(eventId, async (newSettings) => {
      const eventToLoad = newSettings[eventId];
      await createTimeEntry(eventToLoad.tagIds)
    });
  };

  const setDefaultTag = async (eventId: string, callback: (newSettings: ISettings) => Promise<void>) => {
    const defaultTag: string = "default_tag"

    const SetSettingsAsync = new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
      setSettings((prevSettings) => {
        const updatedSettings: ISettings = { ...prevSettings };
        let currentTagIds = [...updatedSettings[eventId].tagIds];
        currentTagIds.push(defaultTag);

        updatedSettings[eventId] = {
          ...updatedSettings[eventId],
          tagIds: currentTagIds,
        };
        callback(updatedSettings).then(() => resolve())
        return updatedSettings
      })
    })
    await SetSettingsAsync
  }
```

## 3. Use [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect)

> useEffect is a React Hook that lets you synchronize a component with an external system.

This one is particularly useful if you want a side-effect that runs every time Settings changes. If you are always calling `createTimeEntry` after `Settings` are updated this is a useful.

Although, this may not be what is desired, or be wary to apply this to all use-cases. Read [You Might Not Need an Effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect). But in this case it will work fine.

Note that you'll have to store EventId in state as well.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const eventToLoad = Settings[EventId]
  await createTimeEntry(eventToLoad.tagIds)
  // this dependency array means everytime `Settings` OR 'EventId' is updated we should
  // run this code, but also will guarantee `Settings`/'EventId` is up-to-date
}, [Settings, EventId])
```

### Aside/Opinions/Thoughts

The last `useEffect` pattern is typically understood by most experienced React devs, and it would be best to refactor (imho) to this sort of utilization, and adjust your state data structures appropriately.

- Is it necessary to have these callbacks distinct and seperate (IE. why not combine handleCreateTimeEntry and setDefaultTag)?
- Is a pure function with returns a solution here? (See 1st Answer Suggestion)

While all of these "answers" are valid solutions, I would recommend either the 1st or 3rd option since they are the least complex. However, I believe the 1st can be more fragile in some cases (ie, if setDefaultTag/handleCreateTime entry is called multiple times in a row). But this is just a question of is the code effort is worth solving this case (is it worrisome enough? happens enough?)